# HTML DIV - How to get View Selection Source?

Tags: html, image

I set my DIV as **contenteditable = true** so I can capture image from clipboard. I managed to paste the image. When I right click and check View Selection Source, I able to see the base64 value. Once i copy and save the base64 value,  I managed to see the image I paste earlier. How do I get the View Selection Source value programatically.? Any advice or any link for references is highly appreciated.

HTML

```
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>Screen Shot Example</Title>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:258px;
    height:165px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 71px;
    top: 59px;
}
</style>
</Head>

<Body>
<div id="apDiv1" contenteditable='true'>Paste Test</div>
</Body>
</Html>
```

Image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the `img` element in your `contenteditable` element, and grab its `src` attribute.

Note that this [doesn't work with Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49141).

You can detect `webkit-fake-url` pseudo-protocol and branch your code to inform the user that you can't grab their image on their browser.

Comment: how do i get the img element in contenteditable element? Only use Firefox, so shouldn't be problem i guess.

Comment: @chinna_82 Use JavaScript to do it.

Comment: i used DIV as contenteditable. Fnding how i can get img element from DIV. Appreciate if you could share some links.